# Add Source Code's Lint step to Gitlab CI stages

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

There's some way to add a source code **linting** step to a **gitlab ci** enabled project?

So as the stage fails if **lint** detects critical issues?

Comment: I feel like there's some hidden meaning in your question, some things that are not completely explicit.

Comment: You can lint everything except .gitlab-ci.yml (which has a sort of automatic lint).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course it's possible.

Simply add a job that will run the linter of your choice. As long as your linter returns a non zero code when it finds an error, that will work.

Here's an example to add to your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
lint:
    stage: test
    script:
        - linter src/
```